# How to get MAC address of the chosen interface and adapter?

Tags: c#, .net, network-interface

how can I get the MAC address of the chosen interface and adapter? I know how to get all MAC addresses from the Ethernet interface but my goal is to get a MAC address from a specific adapter. For example, I've got 3 Ethernet adapters (names of adapters: Ethernet, Ethernet 2, VMware) and my goal is to get the MAC address of Ethernet adapter. I've tried: searching in C# docs, looking on other stack threads, and searching on other sites.  My code:

```
        List<string> macs = new List<string>()
        { "000569","000C29","001C14","005056","080027","00155D","080027"};
        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            // Only consider Ethernet network interfaces
            if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet &&
                nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                string cllc = nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                char[] array = cllc.Substring(0, 6).ToCharArray();

                foreach (char mac in array)
                {
                    if (macs.Contains(mac.ToString()))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Each of the NetworkInterface objects that you're iterating over ought to have a Name property (nic.Name). Do any of these match the adapter you're looking for?

Comment: @RogerN Yes, some of them match.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get MAC address of specific adapter by adapter name this below code is working. This example tries to find adapter with "Ethernet" name.

```
string macAddress=NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                 .Where(x => x.Name =="Ethernet")
                 .Select(x => x.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString())
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the code and it works now.

```
List<string> macs = new List<string>()
{ "000569","000C29","001C14","005056","080027","00155D","080027"};
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
        // Only consider Ethernet network interfaces
    if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet && 
        nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
    {
        string cllc = nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
        if (macs.Contains( cllc.Substring(0, 6)))
            return true;
    }
}
```

I really didn't understand why you've used only first 6 character of MAC address but the above code work properly if the first 6 character of MAC address of your "Up" Ethernet is exist in given list.